# OpenDKIM & OpenDMARC on SLES 15 SP2

Tags: linux, postfix, opendkim, opendmarc

Hello is it possible to install OpenDKIM & OpenDMARC on SLES 15 SP2 through the default repository of OpenSUSE?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [SUSE Packages](https://scc.suse.com/packages) tool to find this information:

- [`opendkim` packages in SUSE SLES SP2 x86_64](https://scc.suse.com/packages?name=SUSE%20Linux%20Enterprise%20Server&version=15.2&arch=x86_64&query=opendkim&module=) => [opendkim
  2.10.3-bp152.3.23](https://scc.suse.com/packages/20491166)
- [`opendmarc` packages in SUSE SLES SP2 x86_64](https://scc.suse.com/packages?name=SUSE%20Linux%20Enterprise%20Server&version=15.2&arch=x86_64&query=opendmarc&module=) => No packages found.